# How to send a request by a private protocol with Python

Tags: python, tcp, network-protocols

I want to send a request to a server which is a private protocol based on TCP (Not HTTP), How Can I send a request using Python?

Comment: Using [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)s? Here is a [tutorial](http://python.talkera.org/python-network-sockets-programming-tutorial/) found at random; you might found snippets on [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/tags/socket/) to learn by example.

Comment: @bufh Actually I forgot the socket, Thanks for reminding me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python sockets are what you are looking for.  Take a look at the Python Socket class at https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

This site includes examples of how to set up a server and client and provides a basic example of the fundamental TCP Communication using Python.  If you need something with more control you may want to look at Scapy: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/

Scapy is a python implementation that provides a framework to control almost all aspects to Network Communication all the way down to Layer 2 (Ethernet Frame).